# Custom pager title strip in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, pager

I need help custom pager indicator for pager title strip in android.Image link given below what i need.

custom_pagerindicator：
[image]

Comment: Please let us know your research

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwhne.png)

Comment: but what code have you tried doing it ..

Comment: have you figured out a solution without using a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout) library could help you achieve your custom strp as per the image attached.

To be more specific, **Indicator Thickness Trick 1** will solve your issue.